# Number of Roots of a Quadratic Modulo Prime Powers

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, polynomials, roots, finite-fields

I am an undergraduate and have been working on some research that I plan to publish. Part of the proof for one of my theorems relies on proving that an equation of the form $ax^2 + bx + c \equiv 0 \pmod{p^y}$ ($p$ an odd prime and $y > 1$ if that ends up mattering) is not "trivial" (by which I mean not every $x$ is a solution) for $x < p$.

My current understanding is that a polynomial of degree $d$ over a finite field either is identically true in the field or has not more than $d$ roots in the field (please correct me if this is wrong). Without getting into what $a,b,c$ are in my proofs (it really doesn't matter for this question), I have proven that $a$ is relatively prime to $p$ (and thus relatively prime to the modulus).

Shouldn't this be sufficient to prove that this polynomial isn't "trivial"? And one step further, the data I've looked at suggests that this polynomial should always have either 0 or two roots - is this sufficient to prove that?

Comment: Are you working $\mod p^y$ or over a finite field of order $p^y$? Because if you just work $\mod p^y$ then a quadratic equation might have more than two roots. For example, $x^2 - 1 \equiv 0 \, (\mod 8)$ is satisfied by $x = 1,3,5,7$. Also, if you want to show the equation is "non-trivial", can't you start with showing that $c \neq 0$ ($\mod p^y$)? Because then $x = 0$ won't be a solution and if $c = 0 (\mod p^y)$ you can just through it away from the equation.

Comment: "My current understanding is that a polynomial of degree $d$ over a finite field either is identically true in the field or has not more than $d$ roots in the field (please correct me if this is wrong)."  You seem to confuse a finite field with integers modulo a prime power.  Which one do you want to ask about?

Comment: @hardmath I am asking about polynomials modulo prime powers.

Comment: @levap Normally that's what I would do, but because of how $c$ is defined, I cannot know that $c \not = 0$ unless I know that the polynomial is non-trivial (it's not worth explaining the whole problem, but I can't use that)

Comment: Also @levap I realize now that I failed to mention $p$ is an odd prime. Could something like the example you gave still happen when $p$ is odd?

Comment: Consider $x^2 \equiv 0 \bmod 9$ then.  It has three roots, $x=0,3,6$.

Comment: You probably want to familiarize yourself with [Hensel lifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#Hensel_lifting). If $x=n$ is a zero of a polynomial $f(x)$ modulo $p$, and $f'(n)$ is not divisible by $p$, then there is a unique solution $x=n'$ of $f(x)\equiv\pmod{p^k}$ such that $n'\equiv n \pmod p$. Modulo $p$ you can take advantage of the fact that $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ is a field.

Comment: @hardmath I suppose it would help here to give some context on the actual problem. This polynomial is being used to, put simply, extend the integers modulo $p^y$ to the integers modulo $p^{y+1}$. So the purpose of the variable $x$ is to take each integer modulo $p^y$ to the $p$ integers equivalent to it modulo $p^{y+1}$. And for more complicated reasons, I don't really care about the case where $x = 0$, so only roots relatively prime to $p$ matter. Does this change things?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I have thought of that, but it turns out $f'(n)$ is divisible by $p$

Comment: In that case it gets trickier...

Comment: @WillCraig: If $p$ is odd, then by showing that $a$ is relatively prime, you can invert it and get an equivalent equation of the form $x^2 + b'x + c' = 0$. Since $p$ is odd, $2$ is invertible so you can complete the square and after a linear substitution $u = x + \frac{b}{2}$ get an equation of the form $u^2 = v$. Since it isn't possible that all numbers will square to the same number $v$ modulo $p^y$, it seems that not all $x$ can be solutions.

Comment: If $p=2$, you can use ideas from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/366756/11619). If $p>2$ you can try to do Hensel, but there are degenerate cases when the roots modulo $p$ coincide. Following Hardmath's example from above, consider $x^2\equiv0\pmod{25}$ and $x^2\equiv 5\pmod{25}$ to get an idea of what may happen when lifting.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I'm not sure I understand. It seems that the equation is equivalent to $\left( x + \frac{b'}{2} \right)^2 = - \left( c' + \frac{b'^2}{4} \right)$. If the right hand side is zero, then $x = -\frac{b'}{2} + 1$ won't be a solution and if the right hand is non-zero then $x = -\frac{b'}{2}$ won't be a solution, no? Of course, the precise number of roots is much more delicate.

Comment: @levap I misread your comment and deleted the one referring to yours.

Comment: @WillCraig Did you show that $x^2+bx+c$ is irreducible modulo $p$ an odd prime iff $b^2-4c$ is not a square modulo $p$ ? In that case it stays irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_{p^{2n+1}}$ and in $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I have reworked my algebra for the full form of the polynomial, and I have found that I can reduce the polynomial to a polynomial of the form $u^2 \equiv v \pmod{p}$, with $u = u(t)$ and $v$ a constant. This reduces the problem to determining if $v$ is a quadratic residue of $p$. Doesn't this imply that the polynomial either has 0 or two roots (depending on the Legendre symbol of $v$ and $p$) since $p$ is an odd prime?